# Exercise with functor, applicative and monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm doing exercises from the book "Programming in Haskell (2nd Edition)" and I have some problems in understanding the following:

"Given the following type of expressions

```
data Expr a = Var a | Val Int | Add (Expr a) (Expr a)
deriving Show
```

that contain variables of some type `a`, show how to make this type into instances of the *Functor*, *Applicative* and *Monad* classes. With the aid of an example, explain what the `>>=` operator for this type does."

I found a solution to the first question, which is the same as here: https://github.com/evturn/programming-in-haskell/blob/master/12-monads-and-more/12.05-exercises.hs (ex. 7), that is type correct.

The problem is that I cannot find out the sense of this exercise and the meaning of what this solution actually does.

Comment: Do you understand what it means for `Expr` to *have* a `Functor` instance? If not, I wouldn't worry about understanding the actual instance just yet.

Comment: I think `Expr a` is too complex to be a good example. Maybe you could try to understand [Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-836) first. (pun intended)

Answer (score 2):

To understand the solution, you need to get an intuition over a `Functor`, an `Applicative` and a `Monad`.

That being said `fmap`, `<*>` and `>>=` is just a way for one to be able to transform a data within an arbitrary `F` in your case that's an `Expr` from `a -> b`

Take a look at the Type class definitions of `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` for example.

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Applicative f where
    <*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Applicative m => Monad m where
    >>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Though on the bigger picture, these functions also execute effects of the algebraic datatype that have the type class instances for it.

For example, I will provide the rough definition of the `Maybe` monad.

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    (Just something) >>= f = f something
    Nothing          >>= _ = Nothing
```

In this context, the bind or `>>=` combinator returns `Nothing` if there is `Nothing` for the input else it applies the arbitrary `f` on `something` such that `f` is a transformation from `a -> Maybe b` which satisfies the definition of the `>>=` combinator which is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` where `m` is the `Maybe` datatype.